# How should I read environment variables at AWS EC2 instance in Reactjs App

Tags: java, reactjs, amazon-ec2, npm, webpack

I want to fetch some credentials from environment variables in my Reactjs app, which would be different for different environment i.e. Dev/staging/prod.

I am doing this in webpack.config.js 
`

```
function getDotenvFilePath(){
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'local'){
        console.log('u r in local ');
        return './.env.local';
    }else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev'){
        console.log('u r in development ');
        return './.env.development';
    }else if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'int'){
        console.log('u r in int ');
        return './.env.int';
    }
}`
```

different files for different environments which I will trigger from maven like this `npm run-script build:int` is that a right approach?

Thanx

Comment: if you created your react app using "create-react-app", you can create .env files for development and production

Comment: Thanx @AngelSalazar But we have not used 'create-react-app'. We have used 'dotenv' package but its not reading .env file values.

Answer (score 1):

small example to read a specific .env file based on the NODE_ENV variable

I am assuming you have [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) plugin setup

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? './.env.development' ? './.env.production'),
      safe: true, 
      systemvars: true, 
      silent: true 
    })
  ]
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thanx a ton. I will try this.

Comment: But I cant use 'dotenv-webpack' package to read env variables from EC2 instance right?

Comment: Dotenv will attach the env variables you define on the file to the process.env object.

Comment: I had this Auth0_domain=domain123 in my .env.development file and I logged it in app.js like this console.log('process.env.Auth0_domain: '+process.env.Auth0_domain); but still no luck :(